# Update nifi Controllers and Processors through API without IDs

Tags: linux, docker, api, ubuntu, apache-nifi

I need to automate nifi bootstraping using docker(specifically nifi-1.17.0).
I want to be able to load a template on each new container instance andi nstead of running the new instance and then logging in to the UI and changing all settings manually, I want to do it automatically within a bash script.
What I need is to update a controller service's fields, and 1 processor's property.
I understand that my workflow is such:
stop processor
disable controller service
update controller service
enable controller service
start processor

and

stop processor
update property
start processor

but I also understand that each time I use the template, all processors and controllers have a different ID.

How can I automate this or use the API if I dont know what ID my processors and controllers will have?
And how do I upload a template and use it through the API?

Thanks in advance to all!

I am running the container using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Args
ENV NIFI_SERVER_IP "some ip"
ENV BASE_DIR "some path"
# Create our workdir
RUN mkdir -p ${BASE_DIR} && cd ${BASE_DIR}
# Set workdir
WORKDIR ${BASE_DIR}
# Copy bootstrap to workdir
COPY script.sh .
# Run the bootstrap
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y
RUN ./script.sh ${NIFI_SERVER_IP}
# Set workdir to new workdir
#WORKDIR ${BASE_DIR}/something i didnt want to share/nifi-1.17.0/bin
# Command to run when container starts
#CMD ["./nifi.sh","start"]
```

and my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install dialog
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tzdata
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install wget -y
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install git-all -y
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/nifi/1.17.0/nifi-1.17.0-bin.zip
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install unzip -y
unzip nifi-1.17.0-bin.zip 
cd nifi-1.17.0
sed -i 's/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g' conf/nifi.properties
sed -i "s/nifi.web.proxy.host=/nifi.web.proxy.host=$1:8443/g" conf/nifi.properties
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install java-11-openjdk -y
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install openjdk-11 -y
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install openjdk-11-jre -y
echo "export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/'" >> ~/.bashrc
cd bin
./nifi.sh start
./nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials admin nifipassword1
./nifi.sh stop
```

Answer (score 1):

You should name each Controller or Processor object in your flow uniquely, and search for them by that name in a setup script. Some of these actions are possible via the NiFi CLI, however I would recommend you automate more complex NiFi Flow configurations via the community Python client [NiPyAPI](https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/) (I am the main author)